# Rewrite - Como redirecionar tudo sem index.php

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewrite

Gostaria de redirecionar todas as requisições do meu servidor Apache para o arquivo test.php e remover da pasta raiz (public_html ou DocumentRoot) o arquivo index.php.

Estou com o seguinte código:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule . test.php [L]
```

Ele funciona desde que o arquivo index.php esteja na pasta raiz. Ao remover o arquivo index.php o Rewrite não funciona e o Apache exibe a lista de todos os arquivos e pastas da minha pasta raiz.

Gostaria de saber se tem como a requisição passar somente pelo arquivo .htaccess?

**Obs.:** Não tenho acesso ao arquivo httpd.conf ou apache2.conf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mudando o padrão de `.` para `^` resolve o problema. O `.` significa que deve haver pelo menos um caracter no pedido, já o `^` não. Quando o diretório raiz `/` é carregado, que é um pedido em branco, o padrão `.` não irá corresponder a isso e irá procurar um `index.php` definido. Caso não ache nada, o padrão não é carregado, porque ele não está recebendo nada.

O código ficará assim:

```
RewriteRule ^ test.php [L]
```

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32814657/rewrite-redirecting-all-without-index-php)

Answer (score 1):

Veja se isso é o suficiente:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.seusite.com.br$
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.seusite.com.br/test.php [L,R=301]
```

você pode ser mais agressivo e tentar usar o `Redirect`:

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect / http://www.seusite.com.br/test.php
```

Ainda é possível você definir o `directoryIndex` dentro do .htacess:

```
DirectoryIndex test.php
```

Eu aconselharia usar somente este ultimo caso dentro do seu .htacess apague o index.php e veja o resultado.